# Can someone explain FormCollection parameter in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web application and it has two controller classes. The two controllers have an action with FormCollection parameter with HTTPPost attribute decorated. If I click on Form submit button then which action will be triggered to capture the form's values within the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Form Collection class we can capture the form's values within the controller.There are many ways to fetch these values and Form Collection is the one of them.

http://tutorial.techaltum.com/Form-collection-in-MVC.html
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-formcollection-in-mvc-controller/

Follow above link It will help you to understand more.

Comment: Thanks for your link. I understood the usage of FormColletion parameter. My question is  I have Two controllers have an action say "Index" and "Index1" with FormCollection parameter and also HTTPPost attribute decorated. If I click on Form submit button then which action will be triggered to capture the form's values within the controller. I hope You understand the question